# Does LinkedHashMap also treeifyBin/treefybucket when reached a threshold?

Tags: java, collections

this question is an mere attempt for clarification:

1. since LinkedHashMap extends HashMap and most of its methods like
   `putval()` , can we safely assume that LinkedHashMap also converts
   its data structure like TreeMap after reaching a certain threshold ?
2. and if that is the case how the iterator would behave once we change
   the datastructure to tree  ?
3. would it behave like the LinkedHashMap's iterator(insertion order) or HashMap's
   iterator(sorted order for treenodes) .

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: `put()` extends from HashMap and LinkedHashMap doesn't override this method.
Q2/Q3： it's similar to HashMap, and in it's source code, there is no special handle on treeNode, you could compare the method `final class EntryIterator extends HashIterator` and `final class LinkedEntryIterator extends LinkedHashIterator` to know the details